# Antebellum Newspaper Data

Tags: data-request, usa, media

Is there data on the circulation numbers for newspapers in the antebellum (pre-1861) United States? I'm also interested in any other pieces of data about these newspapers.

Comment: Yes, and I just edited my post to address that typo.

Comment: Have you looked through https://www.lib.umn.edu/faq/5361 ? Seems promising but maybe not for your time period

Comment: Maybe this helps http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4981/dataset-of-major-newspapers-content

Answer (score 2):

The [US Newspapers Directory](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/search/titles/) has a substantial amount of metadata about publication locations & dates, but nothing on circulation. Some bulk data/linked data access is apparently available.

It's part of the broader [Chronicling America](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/) site, which offers digitised newspapers from 1836 onwards; 1770 titles, 1.36m issues, 9.55m pages. (Of course, the majority of these will be post-1860s)

Answer (score 1):

The [NYTimes Archive](http://www.nytimes.com/ref/membercenter/nytarchive.html) goes back to 1851.

[Here's](http://www.nytimes.com/1864/07/23/news/the-president-and-peace.html) a random example, showing that the articles are machine readable.

They also have an [API](http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/read/article_search_api_v2) for developers.

And they have an N-gram tool called [Chronicle](http://chronicle.nytlabs.com/?keyword=Great%20War.World%20War%20I) where you can click on the results to view each article.

[image]