# How can I sufficiently rigorously create a list from news reports?

Tags: best-practice

For a research paper I'm currently working on, I need to compile a dataset based on various news reports. Obviously, there's no way I can be sure that my list is exhaustive, but how can I compile data based on scattered news reports I find on the Internet in a way that is sufficiently rigorous and acceptable for an academic publication?

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4981/dataset-of-major-newspapers-content